# Please help with proving or disproving the statement related to vector induced norm of real symmetric matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-norms, spectral-radius

Consider any vector induced norm (need not be just p-norm). I need to prove or disprove that for any real symmetric matrix A and vector induced norm $||.||$,

$$
||A|| = \rho (A)
$$

where $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius (largest eigen value in modulus).

Please provide any example if it can be disproved. Thank you.

Comment: Unless $A$ is a scalar matrix (whether $A$ is symmetric is unimportant), the equality does not hold in general: pick an invertible matrix $P$ such that $\|PAP^{-1}\|_2>\rho(A)$ and define a vector norm $\|x\|=\|Px\|_2$. Then $\|A\|=\|PAP^{-1}\|_2>\rho(A)$.

Comment: how do you prove that such a matrix P exists?

Comment: @user1551 Also no such P exists. Since P is an invertible matrix, PAP-1 is a similarity transformation and has exactly same eigen values as A.

Comment: @SundaresanG That's what user1551 is counting on: similarity can affect $\|\cdot\|_2$ without affecting $\rho$, so you can alter the matrix norm without affecting the spectral radius. Honestly, it also suffices to find two matrix norms which disagree on a single symmetric matrix because then they can't both equal the spectral radius.

Answer (score 0):

I am disappointed with the comments. However I found an example to disprove.

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
2&-1\\
-1&3\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It is easy verify that 1norm is 4 but 2norm is less than 4.